# Shortcuts for subscript and superscript in non-math context

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

all. I need some help with subscript and superscript in a non-math context. I am using `\textsubscript` now but this turned out to be very inconvenient. I tried `$a_1$` but the letter turned out to be in italic, which is not what I want. Is there a similar shortcut for sub(super)script that does not make letters in italics? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need this for chemical formulas?

Comment: No.. I need it for logic.

Comment: Maybe you can add an example, so you can get better help; not that Mico's answer i s bad, but sometimes it happens that there are better ways for accomplishing a task.

Comment: Basically, I need to say something like "o1 is F1, o2 is F2... on is Fn" (1, 2,..., n as subscripts), and I also need to refer to them a lot in one single paragraph. And that's it.

Comment: A proper example would help to ensure the most effective answer for your situation, as @egreg suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the following two shortcut macros

```
\newcommand\tsub[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tsup[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

convenient enough?

Comment: Wouldn't `\newcommand\tsub{\textsubscript}` be more efficient?

Comment: Ha. thanks. this shows i'm new to the latex world...

Comment: @campa - I believe it's good programming practice to indicate explicitly how many arguments a given macro is supposed to take. If sheer brevity/terseness were a goal, I'd go with `\let\tsb\textsubscript` and `\let\tsp\textsuperscript`.

Comment: I'd use `\newcommand*` ....